# print current row when next row gets higher

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to get the current row, in column 3, if the second row has increased. For example, this is my input file

```
 9* 2.3 0.3 1.01101  28.8
10* 3   0.3 1.01091  20.8
11* 3   0.3 1.01091  20.8
12* 3.6 0.9 1.00578  20.8
13* 4   0.9 1.00553  0
14* 4   0.9 1.00553  0
15* 4.5 1.4 1.01251  0
18* 6   1.4 1.01334  25
19* 6.5 1.8 1.00742  25
20* 7   1.8 1.00832  8.3
21* 7   1.8 1.00832  8.3
22* 7.6 2.4 1.01134  8.3
23* 8   2.4 1.00443  0
24* 8   2.4 1.00443  0
```

And I want the output like this

```
11* 3   0.3 1.01091 20.8
14* 4   0.9 1.00553 0
18* 6   1.4 1.01334 25
21* 7   1.8 1.00832 8.3
24* 8   2.4 1.00443 0
```

So, if you notice that I only picked the row before the next row, in column 3, gets higher. I tried this script but it seems that it only takes when previous row equal to the next row.

```
awk  '$3==last{next} {last=$3} 1'
```

Comment: Why is `24*` in the output?

Comment: It doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl solution:

```
perl -ane 'print $prev if $F[2] > $col3; $col3 = $F[2]; $prev = $_' < file
```

It doesn't output the line `24*` as 2.4 isn't greater to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $3>p3{print p0} {p3=$3; p0=$0}' file
11* 3   0.3 1.01091  20.8
14* 4   0.9 1.00553  0
18* 6   1.4 1.01334  25
21* 7   1.8 1.00832  8.3

$ awk 'NR>1 && $3>p3{print p0} {p3=$3; p0=$0} END{print p0}' file
11* 3   0.3 1.01091  20.8
14* 4   0.9 1.00553  0
18* 6   1.4 1.01334  25
21* 7   1.8 1.00832  8.3
24* 8   2.4 1.00443  0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering why your command fails, let me analyze it for you :

```
$3==last{next}
{last=$3}
1
```

This essentially does :

- `$3==last{next}`: if the third column is equal to the stored value `last`, skip to the next line
- `{last=$3}`:  if the third column is different from the stored value `last`, set `last` to the value of the third column.
- `1`: print the current line.

As you see, you print the current line and not the previous line. All you had to do is store the previous line and print that one (with exception of the first record). We also learn that your input is clearly sorted, otherwise, you would not have used the equal sign. An updated version of your script would be :

```
($3!=last) && (NR>1){print prev}
{last=$3; prev=$0}
```

As you see, by reversing the logic a bit, we could move the print statement to the first line and then store the previous line afterward.